# Python Multiprocessing, TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, python-multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing and I need your help.

I have four variables that each of them can take up to 4 values (integers or floats) and I stored all of them in a list called `par=[A, B, C, D]`. (see below)

I have created a list of possible combinations with `par = itertools.product(*par)` .

Then, I call a function `func1`, that takes these arguments and some more and calculates stuff. With the results of the `func1`, I call another function that calculates stuff and then writes to a file.

I want to run these as a whole in parallel with `multiprocessing.Pool` I thought to embed `func1` and `func2` in another function, called `func_run`, and map this with the list `par` I created above.

To summarize, my code looks like:

```
#values that I will use for func1
    
r   = np.logspace(np.log10(5),np.log10(300),300)
T   = 200*r

#Parameters for the sim
A = [0.1, 0.05, 0.001, 0.005]
B = [0.005, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1]
C = [20, 60, 100, 200]
D = [10, 20, 40, 80]

#Store them in a list
par = [A, B, C, D]

#Create a list with all combinations
par = list(itertools.product(*par))             

def func_run(param):
    for i in range(len(param)):

# Call func1
        values = func1(param[i][0],param[i][1],param[i][2], param[i][3], r, T)

        x = values[0]
        y = values[1]
        # and so on
        
# Call func2
        results = func2(x,y,...)

        z = results[0]
        w = results[1]
        # and so on

        data_dict = {'result 1': [param[i][0]], 'result 2' : [param[i][1]]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_dict)
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                df.to_csv(f, header=False)
      
    return
```

Then, I call the `func_run` with `multiprocessing`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=4)
results = pool.map(func_run, par)
```

As a result, I get a, `TypeError` with traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-14-5ce94acfd95e>", line 5, in run
values = calc_val(param[i][0],param[i][1],param[i][2], param[i][3], r, T)
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f45146f68f66> in <module>()
      1 pool    = Pool(processes=4)
----> 2 test    = pool.map(run,par)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
264         in a list that is returned.
265         '''
--> 266         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
267 
268     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
642             return self._value
643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
645 
646     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Unfortunately, it is impossible to add the whole functions and what are they doing because they are hundreds of lines. I hope that you can get the feeling though even though you cannot really reproduce it by yourselfs.

Is it possible to run something like this with multiprocessing or I need a different approach?
It would be great if anyone can help me understand the error and make it run.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the full traceback instead of just the error message without a context.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited it to make it as "code" as possible with a traceback, but still I am not sure if this can help as I explain above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of

```
par = list(itertools.product(*par))
```

is a list of tuples of floats (and ints). [`Pool.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) takes an *iterable* as the 2nd argument and maps over its items, passing them individually to given *func*. In other words in the function `func_run(param)` *param* is not a list of tuples of numbers, but a tuple of numbers, and so

```
param[i][0]
```

is trying to access the *ith* float object's 0th item, which of course makes no sense, and so the exception. You probably should remove the for-loop in `func_run()`:

```
def func_run(param):
    values = func1(param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], r, T)
    ...
```